# When we are applying credit to an order and there is a zero balance there is not an invoice created

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice

When we are applying STORE CREDIT to an order and there is a zero balance at the end of the order, magento does NOT create an invoice for some weird reason. We need to be able to print out an invoice to send to the customer even if they have not had to pay anything.

Basically MAGENTO isn't creating an invoice on an order which has a 0 balance. The reasons why some orders have a 0 balance is because the customer used store credit.

Is this related to our settings? Can someone help?

Comment: As per Magento Standard you have to create invoice manualy form admin order level.

Comment: This didn't really answer my question.

Comment: my question is that have you do some code for that when you place order then invoice is automatic created?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: please make sure that

Comment: can you explain what code should be their to generate this?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-invoice-from-order/

Comment: @Adam were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?